# How to ignore special symbols in SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to get this sentence stored in SQL.
"**WorkForceNow (WFN): Production:  DS work for new schema on Training Farm**"

My Insertion Code :

```
Dim sqq, sqq1 As New SqlConnection   
            sqq.ConnectionString = "##Conection string##"  
            sqq.Open()
Dim sqq2 As String = "Insert into [Reviews] values('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"  
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(sqq2, sqq)   
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()   
            sqq.Close()
```

**Error :**

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

How to ignore special symbols in SQL?

Comment: But it looks like the field has max capacity nothing about special letters.

Comment: use parameters, do NOT concat that sql together.

Comment: creating sql by concatenation of user input is a bad practice anyway (prone to sql injection attack) - you should definitely use parameters.

Comment: But, its not allowing to insert into SQL.    
Throwing the error which mentioned above.

Comment: Hey, i got it was issue this with character length.

Before : **varchar(150)** 
Now : **varchar(max)**

Comment: its working fine now thanks.